# Miss the bottom of the bitmap when I take a snapshot with an Action Bar. Android

Tags: android, bitmap, view, android-actionbar, snapshot

I have a problem when I take a **snapshot** of my screen. The bitmap paint everything but the *bottom of the view*. I attach some code of the layout and also from the snapshot call.

The activity has also an **action bar** with **TabListeners**. So it has 3 tabs and few buttons in the action bar (they are shown on the snapshot. Could be nice if I could delete them as well in the snapshot causes I don't need them at all ^^U But it is not the important thing).

**Snapshot:**

```
    private void snapShot() {
        Log.d("On snapShot","At beggining");
        Bitmap bitmap;
        getWindow().getDecorView().setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);    
        try{
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWindow().getDecorView().getDrawingCache());
        }catch (IllegalStateException e){
            bitmap = null;
        }
        try{    
            Log.d("On snapShot", "inside Try");
            File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();              
            if (root.canWrite()){
                pic = new File(root,"pic.png");
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(pic); 
                bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out); 
                out.flush(); 
                out.close();
            }
        }catch(IOException e) { 
            Log.e("BROKEN", "Could not write file " + e.getMessage());
        }
        getWindow().getDecorView().setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);       
     }
```

**Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal" 
  android:layout_weight="20"
  >
  <com.example.daemon.views.CaptionView
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id = "@+id/legendView"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  </com.example.daemon.views.CaptionView>

        <View 
            android:id="@+id/lineSeparation"
            android:background="#F000"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
         /> 
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <com.example.daemon.views.ChartView
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/viewChart"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  </com.example.daemon.views.ChartView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Add a little more code, where the action bar and the tabs are created.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);    // Set the application works only on Landscape orientation.
    actionBar = getActionBar();                                     // Creates the action bar.
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);                
    Log.i(TAG, "On create");
    String label1 = "one day";              
    Tab tab = actionBar.newTab();           // Creates a tab
    tab.setText(label1);                

    // Links the tab created with an existing Fragment 
    TabListener<Tab1Fragment> tl = new TabListener<Tab1Fragment>(this, label1, Tab1Fragment.class);     
    tab.setTabListener(tl);                 // Makes the tab  respond the touch events.
    actionBar.addTab(tab);                  // Add the tab to the action bar.
```

PNG when i push the snapshot:
[image]

How it should appear, picture from my camera:
[image]

The problem (I think) is that when the bitmap is created its maximun height is 732 (the same than the view) but it start capturing the view from the top (including the action bar that is not on the view) so it only can paint the first 732 rows. The point is that if I said to start after the action bar, an error appear because "y + height cannot be > bitmap.height" so... what can I do?

Thank you a lot!!!

Comment: As I said, I don't care about the buttons. The point is that the bottom of the view is not showed.

Comment: according to u r point of view the bottom part of the screen is missing completely...or the bottom part is shown with black...

Comment: Just add that the "button" for take the snapshot is a fragment in the action button. If it makes any different.

Comment: I added pictures of what it happens when I take the snapshot and how it should be (picture from a camera).

Comment: I also tried to hide the action bar, take the snapshot and show it again and it doesn't work either.

Comment: Could delete the answer as answer in order to know that this question has no answer, please? 
I will add more code about how I create the tab if it helps.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. 
It was hard to find it but it's quite easy.
I just add to the first LinearLayout (the one which content all the others) an id. 
Then I can create the bitmap finding the view by id.

In the layout I add: `android:id="@+id/mainLayout"`
and then in the activity:

```
int id = R.id.mainLayout;
View view = findViewById(id);                   
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWindow().findViewById(id).getDrawingCache());
```

Thanks for the support and I hope this will help to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps setting the size of your BitMap might solve your problem.

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int width = metrics.widthPixels;
int height = metrics.heightPixels;
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWindow().getDecorView().getDrawingCache(), 0, 0, width, height);
```

Comment: Not, it doesn't fix it. It gaves me exactly the same image that I took before. The reason is because the height is 732 (without the action bar) and that is what the heightPixels gives me but the Bitmap.createBitmap starts from the beggining, like it started from -40.
Thank you for trying.

Comment: I think the problem is that i cannot have the DecorView and it has to be another view which only takes the layout and not all the thing there are in the screen.

Comment: Try `getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();`

Comment: It doesn't work either, shows the same. But we're close because if I write `getWindow().findViewById(R.id.viewChart).setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);` it stores the second part of the screen, the chart.

Comment: try to get the root view from the like  this `getWindow().findViewById(R.id.viewChart).getRootView()`

Comment: Nothing, just having the same problem. It always print the action bar and not the bottom.